# How to implement CSRF validation in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm developing my own authentication function, but I'm not using the `CSRF` verification part, and I would do it (`FOSUserBundle` is installed and configured).

Here is my `PHP` controller :

```
public function checkLoginAjaxAction() {
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $success = false;
    $responseCode = 300;
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserBy(array('username' => $request->request->get('_username')));

        if ($user) {
            $encoderManager = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $encoderManager->getEncoder($user);
            $encodedPass = $encoder->encodePassword($request->request->get('_password'), $user->getSalt());

            $token = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');
            $res = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->isTokenValid(new CsrfToken('calendar-connection-form', $token));
            dump($res); // always return false...

            if ($user->getPassword() === $encodedPass /* && $res*/) { // but $res is false everytime
                $responseCode = 200;
                $success = true;
            } else {
                $responseCode = 400;
            }
        }

    }
    $return = json_encode(array('responseCode' => $responseCode, 'success' => $success));
    return new Response($return, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
}
```

In my twig :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('calendar-connection-form') }}" />
```

So, how can I implement the `CSRF` token in my authentication ?

By the way, if you see some improvement, tell me (**I didn't do the connection part, just the verification, for the moment**).

Thanks

Comment: OK and what's the question? Also google a bit for `CSRF`. You should find out that the title "*Connect a user using csrf with Symfony2*" doesn't make a sense.

Comment: Why it doesn't make sens ? You answer is really not helpful. You should give me more details to make me understand. By the way, I said that I wanted to implement the `CSRF` token in my authentication, I commented the line which always returned false, so here is my question : how can implement `CSRF` token ?

Comment: Seriously? Try to think about it for a while. `CSRF` is an attack vector. So you want to "*connect an user using an attack vector*"? If you were able to correctly rephrase it to "*how can implement `CSRF` token*", why you don'y change the title of your question?

Comment: I did. I guess I don't really understand `CSRF` token... I wanted to do that because I saw it in the Symfony2 forms...

Comment: And isn't a [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/csrf_in_login_form.html) enough?

Comment: I read it but maybe I just missed some important details. I will take a look

Comment: I have not tried this myself.  Verify that your client side form actually has a csrf token value, verify that $token in your controller ends up with the same value and verify that the token is also in your session data.  If these all check out then you might need to dive into the csrf token manager code to see what is going on.